# Email sent to a campaign members not changing campaign status

Tags: marketing-cloud, campaign-member

We have sent email to campaign members, we can see the contact have recieved the email and opened.

But we want also when contact clicked on email the campaign member status should change to clicked in campaign details.

Is it possible?

Comment: If you can redirect to vf page and call some apex code and update your campaign , then YES!

Comment: How I can redirect to vf? That mean there is no way we can configure/map fields using marketing cloud connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map campaign member status inside marketing cloud connect.